# I need help adding 30 days to today's date using PHP

Tags: php

I have a user system for my website. I need to make something that adds 30 days to todays date.

UPDATE:
I decided to go with an integer instead of a date.

Here's what I did. I set things up so that when someone pays their bill it sets their "Days" value to (value) + 30

I made a cron job that takes away 1 day from every user's "Days".
Obviously, I set the cron job to run once per day.

Comment: Read up on DateTime : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 9):

Use `strtotime` and `date` as below.

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days"));
```

**OR**

```
<?php
   echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."\n";

   echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', mktime(date('h'),date('i'),date('s'),date('m'),date('d')+30,date('Y')))."\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

First you can add date like this

```
$iSecsInDay = 86400;
$iTotalDays = 30;
$user_signup = time() + ($iSecsInDays * $iTotalDays);
```

Then you can use the timestamp to generate date in any way you want, like

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', $user_signup);
```

Full reference can be found here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION

Comment: I don't know how you are using it or where you are using it. To do the calculation you have to move this in a constructor or in a function probably.

Comment: Basically what I'm doing is creating a variable called $user_signup that needs to = todays date plus 1 month. Which I then write into the mysql database using insert into blah blah blah. Make sense?

Comment: Why don't you move the code in the function that is inserting and doing the mysql stuff. Why you want a constant? If you want a constant. Then the code needs to be changed. You want a constant to use in other places too? Yes/No?

Comment: Hmm... I'll try moving it into the mysql function.

Comment: don't forget to remove "private" keyword for that.

Comment: Well, I tried that and it isn't working. Thanks for your help but I'm definitely going to need to research more on this one. I thought it would be an easy fix but it's not.

Comment: Updated the code to make it more logical for usage in general case. I don't know why its not working for you. :(

Comment: `$iSecsInDays` should be `$iSecsInDay`

Answer (score 2):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.

```
strtotime('+30 days', time());
```

Answer (score 1):

`$NewDate=Date('y:m:d', strtotime("+30 days"));`

[strtodate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) :

```
int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )
```

The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add +30 days to the actual date and introduce in mysql you could use:

**$nextMonthDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+30 days",time()));**

Y-m-d H:i:s is the format to MySQL DATETIME.

**Example:**

Actual date: 
echo echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()); --> 2013-03-08 00:37:23

+30 days:    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+30 days",time())); --> 2013-04-07 00:37:23

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a function directly to a variable of a class. This is why you are getting the additional error. Consider moving it to your constructor.

```
... 
private $user_signup = null;

public function __construct() {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
    $this->user_signup = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
...
```

Also see [Assigning a function's result to a variable within a PHP class? OOP Weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562397/assigning-a-functions-result-to-a-variable-within-a-php-class-oop-weirdness) for more information.